# I want to change values below 60 in a column of my dataframe but values below 10 are not taken with it

Tags: r

I have a dataset and i want to change values in my column to "No" and "Yes"

This is the dataset:

```
gender      age     creat     eGFR      CKD
1      1 20.75420  70.35006 66.77359 66.77359
2      1 40.48984 102.39087 37.64458 37.64458
4      1 38.91398  92.26064 43.07771 43.07771
5      1 27.57514  71.13583 63.15280 63.15280
6      0 51.90974 218.35305 10.57759 10.57759
7      1 25.56240  86.98399 50.23518 50.23518
```

In the  column called "CKD" i want to change all the values below 60 to "Yes" and greater than or equal to CKD to "No".

However, when i run the following code:

```
Student_data_2$CKD[Student_data_2$CKD >= 60] <- "No" 
Student_data_2$CKD[Student_data_2$CKD < 60] <- "Yes"
```

All values are changed except for the values below 10, they stay numeric. For example:

```
  gender      age     creat       eGFR              CKD
1        1 20.75420  70.35006  66.773594               No
2        1 40.48984 102.39087  37.644583              Yes
4        1 38.91398  92.26064  43.077715              Yes
5        1 27.57514  71.13583  63.152798               No
15       0 42.27583 196.62734  12.735807              Yes
16       0 59.43180 185.07882  12.309281              Yes
17       1 21.16721 102.46636  42.413975              Yes
18       0 51.78945 131.65945  19.424971              Yes
19       0 61.89885 253.39297   8.314646 8.31464627872699
20       0 76.81865 215.07378   9.225582 9.22558204994784
22       0 53.63316 236.28427   9.519215 9.51921545447276
23       1 31.24610  93.35322  44.548002              Yes
```

Does anyone know what is the problem with my code?

Comment: @melissa Kay's answer is good, but I strongly suggest you **Never** delete data.  Create a new column; call it  "CKD OK?" or some such.  When it comes time to publish, it's easy to make a `table` out of any subset of the columns in your array.

Comment: I might also add that your "gender" column appears to represent the genetic **sex**, not the gender (and ignores the possibility of some XXY people showing up in your study!).  Why is this column encrypted, instead of reading "M" or "F"?  And one more suggestion: you have far more digits of precision than the source data support.  I mean, really: age to a precision of  five minutes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As soon as you run your first line of code, all the numbers become converted to characters, so your second line isn't behaving as expected.  You need to create a new column or do the entire comparison at once.  Try this:

```
Student_data_2$CKD  <- ifelse(Student_data_2$CKD >= 60, "No", "Yes")
```